# How to prove simple transitivity from faithful transitivity immediately from stabilizers?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, abelian-groups, group-actions

The question comes from first few pages of Marcel Berger's textbook "Geometry I". Below is an excerpt in page 8:

> 1.5.3. One always has
> $$G_{g(x)}=gG_xg^{-1}.$$
> In other words, $G_{g(x)}$ and $G_x$ are conjugate subgroups of $G$,
> and in particular are always isomorphic. Example 1.4.4.1 is an
> $\underline{\textrm{immediate consequence}}$ of this remark.

where Example 1.4.4.1 is a proposition

> 1.4.4.1. Proposition. If $G$ is an abelian group, any faithful transitive action is simply transitive.

I have no difficulty in proving the claims in 1.5.3 and proposition 1.4.4.1 per se, but the last sentence of 1.5.3 (underlined in black) frustrated me. When $G$ is abelian, the two stabilizers merge into one, i.e., $G_x=G_{g(x)}$. But then I don't know how to proceed to establish simple transitivity. How to get a contradiction against faithfulness if there are another element in $G$ that sends $x$ to $g(x)$? I believe it will greatly deepen my understanding of concepts involved, so I greatly appreciate it if you can help me figure out how to prove the simple transitivity (immediately) using results of 1.5.3. Thank you.

Comment: If it is faithful and transitive, then for all $x,y$ there exists $g$ with $gx=y$, so $G_x=G_y$. Faithflness then implies that $G_x=\{e\}$, so no two distinct elements can do the same thing to $x$.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures like that. They're difficult to search for and do not render on some devices.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Can you please explain in a bit more details for each of the three claims: 1) $gx=y \Rightarrow G_x=G_y$, 2) faithfulness $\Rightarrow G_x=\{e\}$ and 3) no two distinct elements of $G$ sending $x$ to $y$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user5280911: 1.5.3 tells you that $G_y=G_{g[x]}$ is a conjugate of $G_x$; but in an abelian group, $gG_xg^{-1}=G_x$. Transitivity tells you that you can get from $x$ to *any* element $y$, so all one point stabilizers are equal. In a faithful action, the only element that can fix every point is $e$, so the point stabilizers must all be trivial. And if $gx=hx$, then $h^{-1}gx = h^{-1}hx = ex = x$, so $h^{-1}g\in G_x=\{e\}$.

Comment: I second Shaun’s comment: pictures often can’t be handled by screen readers, making you post inaccessible to many; and they don’t always render correctly in all devices. Please use MathJax. You’ve been on the side for more than four and a half years, you should know that by now.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: To be more specific, 1) As I said in the original question, $G_x=G_y$ because $G$ is abelian. How to establish it using faithful and transitive? 2) 1 (the identity transformation) send $x$ to $x$. Under faithflness, the injectiveness of the action clearly infers that the preimage of 1 is $\{e\}$, but why there is no other bijective transformation sending $x$ to $x$? 3) Even having $G_x=\{e\}$, how to prove this point, because we don't have in general that $y=x$?

Comment: As I said: faithful tells you that the intersection of all one point stabilizers must be trivial (the only element of $G$ that can act the same way that $e$ does is $e$). Transitivity plus abelianness plus 1.5.3  tells you they are all equal. If they are all equal and the intersection is trivial, then they are all trivial. And as I wrote in the last comment: if $g$ and $h$ both send $x$ to $y$, then $h^{-1}g$ sends $x$ to $x$.

Comment: You are not using “faithful and transitive” to establish $G_x=G_y$. You are using 1.5.3 and abelianness to establish that if $x$ and $y$ are in the same orbit, then $G_x=G_y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general fact of group actions: if $g$ and $h$ do the same thing to $x$, that is, if $gx=hx$, then $h^{-1}g\in G_x$. This follows by applying $h^{-1}$ to both $gx$ and to $hx$, and using that in a group action $\sigma(\tau x) = (\sigma\tau)x$, and that $ex = e$.

This is a general fact about group actions: the intersection of the point stabilizers, $\cap_{x\in X} G_x$ is the kernel of the action; that is, the set (actually, normal subgroup) of all elements $g\in G$ such that $gx=x$ for all $x\in X$.

Now, from 1.5.3 you immediately get that if $x$ and $y$ are in the same orbit of the action of $G$, then $G_x$ and $G_y$ are conjugate.

In 1.4.4.1 you have the following hypotheses: the group $G$ is abelian; the action is transitive; the action is faithful.

Since the group is abelian, as you observe, if $x$ and $y$ are in the same orbit of $G$, then $G_x=G_y$. Okay: so, since the action is transitive there is only one orbit, so $G_x=G_y$ for all $x,y\in X$. Since the action is faithful, the kernel of the action is trivial. From the general fact in the second paragraph above, that means that the intersection of all point stabilizers is trivial; but that intersection is just equal to a single point stabilizer (because they are all the same subgroup!) So the one point stabilizers are all trivial.

But that means that if $gx=hx$ for *any* $x$, then $g=h$, by the “general fact” in the first paragraph.

This yields that the action is simply transitive (you already knew it was transitive).
So this follows pretty immediately from the assumptions that $G$ is abelian, and the action is faithful and transitive, since the two general facts I outline are pretty standard and basic about group actions.

Comment: Thank you. I am still thinking why there is only one orbit$\Rightarrow G_x=G_y$. It seems that this statement is true even if $G$ is not abelian, provided only that the $G$-action is transitive. Although for the original question, it's enough to get to $G_x=G_y$ by abelianness, I still hope you can give me a little bit of hint on how to prove $G_x=G_y$ based on only transitivity (or refer me to some link in internet that proves it). Thank you. At the meantime, I will edit my original question to change image to latex text so that it is more friendly to search engine.

Comment: @user5280911: if there is only one orbit then all point stabilizers are **conjugate**, but they need not be equal. For example, $S_3$ acting on $\{1,2,3\}$ in the natural way. The stabilizer of $\{1\}$ is $\{e,(23)\}$; the stabilizer of $2$ is the conjugate subgroup $\{e,(13)\}$; the stabilizer of $3$ is the conjugate subgroup $\{e,(12)\}$. So, no, you don’t get $G_x=G_y$ from just transitivity, you get “$G_x$ is conjugate to $G_y$ for all $x,y\in X$” from transitivity and an application of 1.5.3.

Comment: I'm more than confused. You said "Transitivity tells you that you can get from x to any element y, so all one point stabilizers are equal" in a comment and "Okay: so, since the action is transitive there is only one orbit, so $G_x=G_y$ for all $x,y\in X$" in the answer. So the statement is "transitivity(i.e.,there is only one orbit)$\Rightarrow G_x=G_y$. But the conclusion of the last reply said it is not true. Also, the "$G_x$ is conjugate to $G_y$" is just the result of 1.5.3 which does not assume transitivity. So, I'm totally confused. If we disregard the comments, ...

Comment: ... what on earth does the sentence in the answer "Okay: so, since the action is transitive there is only one orbit, so $G_x=G_y$  for all $x,y∈X$" mean?

Comment: OK, I know what you mean. Abelianness infers that two stabilizers $G_x$ and $G_y$ are equal for a given pair of $x$ and $y$ provided $y$ is reachable from $x$ (there is a $g\in G$ such that $gx=y$). Transitivity, on the other hand, infers that the above equality is true for all $x$ and $y$ in $X$ no matter what. Hope you haven't yet read my last reply; please disregard them. I finally acquired a complete understanding of the "immediate consequence". Thank you very much, Arturo Magidin, I learnt a lot from your help.

Comment: @user5280911: You can delete the old comments if you’ve realized what was happening. My earlier comments, except for the one here above, all were done under the assumption that $G$ was abelian, because that’s what you were asking about. But in the comment above you were asserting something for arbitrary, not-necessarily-abelian, $G$, so now I dropped the assumption.